# How to extract rows from a PHP array after decode

Tags: php, arrays

I create an array on a mobile device :

```
[{"videoID":"1","title":"Amp Demo","URL":"G9xVRDmyK7Q","visible":"0"},    {"videoID":"2","title":"Sam Demo","URL":"S863oGkSQpc","visible":"1"},{"videoID":"3","title":"3 Amp Demo","URL":"G9xVRDmyK7Q","visible":"1"},{"videoID":"4","title":"Sam Demo","URL":"S863oGkSQpc","visible":"0"},{"videoID":"5","title":"Amp Demo","URL":"G9xVRDmyK7Q","visible":"1"},{"videoID":"6","title":"Sam Demo","URL":"S863oGkSQpc","visible":"0"},{"videoID":"7","title":"Amp Demo","URL":"G9xVRDmyK7Q","visible":"1"},{"videoID":"8","title":"Sam ....
```

I use JSON.stringify and send this as an http request to a php file.
In PHP I use:

```
$videoList = $_GET["videoList"];
$videoListArray=json_decode($_GET['videoList']);
var_dump($videoListArray);

array(21) {
[0]=>
object(stdClass)#1 (4) {
["videoID"]=>
string(1) "1"
["title"]=>
string(8) "Amp Demo"
["URL"]=>
string(11) "G9xVRDmyK7Q"
["visible"]=>
string(1) "0"
}
[1]=>
object(stdClass)#2 (4) {
["videoID"]=>
string(1) "2"
["title"]=>
string(8) "Sam Demo"
["URL"]=>
string(11) "S863oGkSQpc"
["visible"]=>
string(1) "1"
}.......
```

So I now have the array in PHP.

How do I loop through the array to access each element.

I need to update an MYSL database with the results of each row.
ie

```
"UPDATE videos SET title = $title, URL = $URL , visible = $visible  WHERE VideoID =     $VideoID";
```

Comment: What have you tried? A [`foreach()`](http://php.net/foreach) could be of use here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a foreach to iterate through the json array of objects like this:

```
<?php 

$jsonData = '[{"videoID":"1","title":"Amp Demo","URL":"G9xVRDmyK7Q","visible":"0"},    {"videoID":"2","title":"Sam Demo","URL":"S863oGkSQpc","visible":"1"},{"videoID":"3","title":"3 Amp Demo","URL":"G9xVRDmyK7Q","visible":"1"},{"videoID":"4","title":"Sam Demo","URL":"S863oGkSQpc","visible":"0"},{"videoID":"5","title":"Amp Demo","URL":"G9xVRDmyK7Q","visible":"1"},{"videoID":"6","title":"Sam Demo","URL":"S863oGkSQpc","visible":"0"}]';

$json = json_decode($jsonData);

foreach ($json as $jsonObj)
{
    echo "UPDATE videos SET title = '$jsonObj->title', 
          URL = '$jsonObj->URL', visible = $jsonObj->visible 
          WHERE VideoID = $jsonObj->videoID"."<br>";
}

?>
```

Produces these queries:

```
UPDATE videos SET title = 'Amp Demo', URL = 'G9xVRDmyK7Q', visible = 0 WHERE VideoID = 1
UPDATE videos SET title = 'Sam Demo', URL = 'S863oGkSQpc', visible = 1 WHERE VideoID = 2
UPDATE videos SET title = '3 Amp Demo', URL = 'G9xVRDmyK7Q', visible = 1 WHERE VideoID = 3
UPDATE videos SET title = 'Sam Demo', URL = 'S863oGkSQpc', visible = 0 WHERE VideoID = 4
UPDATE videos SET title = 'Amp Demo', URL = 'G9xVRDmyK7Q', visible = 1 WHERE VideoID = 5
UPDATE videos SET title = 'Sam Demo', URL = 'S863oGkSQpc', visible = 0 WHERE VideoID = 6
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `foreach()` because you are having multidimensional array

```
foreach($videoListArray as $key)
{
echo $videoListArray[$key][title];
}
```

using this way you you fetch value of elements of each array